# Sending an array of attachments with node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I need to send an email using nodemailer with several attachments, but the number of those attachments must be defined by the size of an array. I know that nodemailer can send more than one attachment, but I have no idea how to send a variable number of attachments.

Here my code:

```
  const files = get(req, "body.data.files");

  files.forEach(file => {
   senderMail.send(file, {
    name: get(req, "body.data.files.name"),
    url: get(req, "body.data.files.url")
    });
  });


   let mailOptions = {
    from: "Me", // 
    sender address
    to: data.personal.user_email, // list of receivers
    subject:
       "An email with attachments"
    text: "someText",
    html: "",
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: name,
        path: url
      }
    ]
  };
```

Some data is obtained from a JSON.

Comment: Did you look in the docs, here: https://community.nodemailer.com/using-attachments/  It's just an array on attachments.  You already have one.

Comment: yeah, but that way I have to enter each element of the array that I want to send, as an element of the array that is sent, and I want that according to the data that comes in the json add a new attachment, if it does not come information that does not .

Comment: well yes.  You have to build up the array!  You can use array.push, you can use map on the list of attachments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare an array in the Nodemailer format and then attach it to the mail object.

```
const files = get(req, "body.data.files");

const attachments = files.map((file)=>{
  return { filename: file.name, path: file.url };
});


let mailOptions = {
  from: "Me", // 
  sender address
  to: data.personal.user_email, // list of receivers
  subject:
      "An email with attachments"
  text: "someText",
  html: "",
  attachments: attachments
};
```